Redeploy .NET Aspire project after resource cleanup
I'm building my first .NET Aspire application and was trialing out the deployment features provided by the Azure Developer CLI.
I initialized my AppHost project with azd init, naming my environment dev.
Next, I executed the azd up command, which provisioned the resources in Azure and deployed my app. I didn't like the name of the resource group though (rg-dev), so I deleted the resource group in Azure, since this documentation states there's no built-in way in Aspire to clean up resources.
I then modified the azure.yaml file to set a different resource group. The modified YAML now looks like:
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-dev/main/schemas/v1.0/azure.yaml.json

name: ProjectName.AppHost
resourceGroup: rg-projectname-${AZURE_ENV_NAME}
services:  
  app:
    language: dotnet
    project: ./ProjectName.AppHost.csproj
    host: containerapp

When next I executed azd up, I get the following error:
ERROR: error executing step command 'deploy --all': failed deploying service 'webui': logging in to registry: failed logging into container registry, token: failed getting ACR token: Post "https://resourcename.azurecr.io/oauth2/exchange": dial tcp: lookup resourcename.azurecr.io: no such host, admin: cannot find registry with name 'resourcename' and subscriptionId 'subscriptionid'
I removed the resourceGroup property from azure.yaml, getting back to my original deploy state. The azd up command then resulted in this error:
ERROR: error executing step command 'deploy --all': getting resource group name: getting default resource groups for environment: dev: resource not found: 0 resource groups with prefix or suffix with value: 'dev'
This leads me to believe that azd is somehow caching the previous deployment and attempting to redeploy the app to the same resources. I deleted all the files & folders created by azd init. Specifically, the following:
.azure directory
.gitignore file
azure.yaml file
next-steps.md file
I reran the azd init command, followed by azd up but the same errors appear.
How do I get azd to "forget" its previous deployments and do a fresh deployment of the app? Also, is there a different way that resources should be cleaned up in order to not run into this issue?
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Are you still facing the issue. @Carl Heinrich Hancke

@Jahnavi - I found a way to work around it, just hadn't got to posting a response. Will do that now.

I managed to resolve this issue by modifying the AppHost that would necessitate a reprovisioning operation. Specifically, I removed the SQL Server resource, along with the web app reference to it.
Executing the azd up command seemed to force a new deployment, provisioning & deploying the application as expected.
I found the azd down command in the help documentation for the Azure Developer CLI. This appears to be the way to clean up resources instead of manually deleting the Resource Group from Azure.

You can redeploy the .NET Aspire-based application by running the following commands in order:
azd package
azd provision --no-state
azd deploy

